# How to create an alias for an ip address on a network on ubuntu?

Tags: webserver, alias

I created a nodejs service (webserver) on a LAN. Now people can only access by typing an IP. We want to type an alias such as "webserver" on the browser instead.

Is this something to set up on the actual machine running Ubuntu? Or maybe on the router?

Comment: For this, you would need custom DNS server. For example another PC runing DNS on it. I am not aware, that this could be set on "classical" router. You could also set DNS record on each computer, that will access that nodejs server. (hosts file)

Comment: @JohnRonald this is a raspberry pi running the webserver, i guess the dns can be set up therein.  I don't know how are the rest of the devices on the LAN be aware of it though, and access using the alias...

Comment: If the avahi (mDNS) service is running, it should be possible to refer to LAN hosts using the `.local` network suffix ex. `webserver.local` where `webserver` is the computer's hostname

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to setup a custom DNS server, then you can define a hostname for your ip address by adding it statically to the file `/etc/hosts`/. The format is simple, and illustrated by the data that is there by default. For example

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

makes it so that the local host can be reached by the hostname "localhost".

That has to be done for each client computer that needs access.

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot!!! but the clients are variable as it is people (like friends) coming to the house, so it wouldn't work would it?

Comment: I don't really understand how changing ect/hosts on client computer makes server reachable VIA "localhost" What am I missing?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff you are apparently missing two things: "as illustrated by the data that is there by default", and "For example". Obviously, you add your own line, in the same format. That is what I tell in the first sentence.